# "Network Error Unable to reach the server" only doing certain actions

Tags: wordpress, contacts, error, search-results, advanced-search

we have a CiviCRM installation under WordPress 4.9.10 and 2 MySQL db: one for Wordpress and one for CiviCRM.
Actually we imported and start to manage more than 5000 contacts.

Everything operate as well, excepting the following actions, returning us a

> **Network Error**
>   Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

- clicking to go on page 2 on a "Search -> Find Contacts" or a "Search
  -> Advanced Search"
- adding a meeting or phone call in the contact summary.

There are **NO ERRORS** adding contributions, registering for events, adding pledges, sending emails.

We see no errors in apache logs too.
Actual PHP variables are:

```
 php_value memory_limit 256M
 php_value max_input_vars 2500
 php_value upload_max_filesize 16M
 php_value register_globals off
 php_value max_execution_time 600
 php_value output_buffering 0
```

Any ideas about to solve it?
TIA -- Francesco

Comment: I think that this has a fix that is merged - but possibly not in this months release but next. It's about your server config - you have something called 'Full Group By' mode enabled in mysql. There is a patch if you feel comfortable backporting

- well that goes for the paging bug - this one "adding a meeting or phone call in the contact summary" - I'm not so sure about - seems different  & unrelated

Comment: Trial done! I confirm that disabling the **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** with this command 
`mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`
solve the problem about the paging, 
but doesn''t solve the problem adding a meeting or phone call in the contact summary.

Comment: @FrancescoGarganese Could you please repost your comment as an answer below?  Thanks! It might also help to post the problem adding a meeting/phone call as a separate question since it appears to be a separate issue.

Comment: On the other issue - it's going to be necessary to capture some more debugging info - with debugging enabled you might be able to get it in your browser by inspecting the response

Comment: Today i try to prepare a small video showing the error, posting to share to you all. Let me know if I can try something to obtain debugging info. About **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** disabling it is a workaround, not a solution; but I put an answer to the question.

Comment: are there some news about the adding a meeting or phone call in the contact summary??

Answer (score 1):

disabling the **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** SQL mode (which it is by default in MySQL 5.7) with this command

`mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

solve the problem about the paging, but it must be considered a workaround.

Comment: This is no longer necessary upgrading to CiviCRM 5.15.0.
The paging problem is solved.